# Print Google Calendar for a year

Tags: google-calendar

I need to print my Google Calendar with all details for a year. (Context - responding to an IRS audit.)

The calendar view (day/week/month) is not good because it cuts off the meeting title. The "Agenda" view is nice (though I wish it showed the Description), but Agenda only shows about a week at a time. I'm thinking the best way to respond to this audit is with a list of my calendar entries in agenda format for the year. One problem... I can't find a way to do that. Agenda is amazingly inflexible and only shows between 5-10 days per page without a way to adjust the date range.

What is the best way to print a Google Calendar in list or agenda view for an entire year?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Looks like I was using the wrong browser or my page just didn't fully load...

1. Turn on the calendars you want to print (left pane)
2. Click 'Agenda' in upper right
3. Click More->Print
4. Enter the required dates in Print Range
5. Print